# Unexpected output after switch to root

Tags: terminal, osx, prompt, bashrc

Does somebody know, why I get `-ne` (probably param from `echo` from section of setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` line 23) after I switch to root?

Here is my `/etc/bashrc`.
Bash 3.2.51, OS X 10.9

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Post the code for your `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, we can likely help you out.

Comment: I already sent in topic, https://gist.github.com/o5/7291505#file-bashrc-L23

Answer (score 0):

There's likely an `if` or `echo` statement in one of your configuration files related to logging in. Using Bash these would be `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in the root user's home directory. Once you become this user you should be in their home directory, take a look.

If the offending code isn't in either of these files then it's likely in a system level equivalent of these files. Not sure where these are on OSX, on a Linux system they'd be in `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile`.